# error:Error in parsing XML Mismatched tags

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I got this error in eclipse and have been searching for hours to find the error. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:src="@drawable/bgora"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bsetbgcolor"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/setBG"
    android:gravity="center"/>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="225dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="center">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivbgora"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:src="@drawable/bgora"/>
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/ivbgbgr"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:src="@drawable/bgbgr"/>   
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/ivbgbla"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="125dp"
    android:src="@drawable/bgbla"/>       


</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

can anyone tell me what is wrong. i cleaned and restarted eclipse multiple times.

Comment: i see nothing wrong with the xml posted

Comment: ya i also check that there is no error...

Comment: Where is it telling you that?  Is it not giving you a specific location or the name of the tag?  What if you open the file in the regular XML Editor?

Answer (score 0):

This is  quite simple as you use HorizontalScrollView, and trying setting a strong width.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >
```

Hope it'll help

Comment: no its okay it works now. i didn't have to change it. I think it was a bug.